# How to use vendorPrefixed 'transform' property in CSS?

Tags: css

Please help me to solve the warning with below code:

```css
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

Comment: Please put some more details like HTML/CSS code, tech stack and exactly where you are getting this warning - browser or command.

With the provided code, there was a space before the ':' colon which might be causing the warning. Not sure but something you can validate.

Answer (score 1):

```css
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8); /* Ch <36, Saf 5.1+, iOS < 9.2, An =<4.4.4 */
      -ms-transform: scale(1.8); /* IE 9 */
          transform: scale(1.8); /* IE 10, Fx 16+, Op 12.1+ */
}
```